# search mysql for string with space after

Tags: mysql

I want to do a select that will take this string "CNA OVERLOAD" and match it searching for the CNA(sp) BUT NOT just CNA.  For example, I would not want the search to give me a positive if I were searching "DECNAT" or "CNASTA SPELLED WRONG" because the CNA does not have a space after it, but it should be TRUE with "THE CNA IS HERE" or "CNA GOOD"

Have tried various escape characters with a substring index and it always gives me anyplace CNA is found.

Comment: `where name like '%CNA% %'` something like that? make sure your column is a varchar, not a fixed length char as it gets padded with white space

Comment: `WHERE column LIKE '%CNA %'`

Comment: Please show us your code so far.